# C++ Boost.Asio errors in async_receive and async_send handlers

Tags: c++, boost-asio

1. Is the connection officially 'dead' when the error_code is not 0?
2. Is it possible for the read handler's bytesReceived parameter to be anything other than 0 when the error_code is not 0? If it is possible, should those bytes be processed or no?

Answer (score 7):

In short, a non-success `error_code` does not guarantee the connection is dead, and for non-composed operations, such `async_receive()`, `bytes_transferred` will be `0` or more on success, and always `0` if an error occurs.

---

A non-success `error_code`  does not officially indicate that the connection is official dead.  For example, a TCP connection still persists in the following cases:

- An outstanding [`basic_stream_socket::async_receive()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_receive/overload1.html) operation cancelled via [`cancel()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel/overload1.html) will resulting in the handler being invoked with an `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` error.
- Only part of a full-duplex connection has been [`shutdown()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/shutdown/overload1.html).  For example, if the receive side of a socket is shutdown, then data can still be sent over the connection via the socket.

For non-composed operations, when an error occurs, `bytes_transferred` will be `0`.  However, a `0` does not indicate an error occurred.  For example, `bytes_transferred` can be `0` and `error_code` can indicate success when using [reactor-style operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) or when an empty buffer is provided.  The `async_receive()` and `async_send()` documentation for [StreamSocketService](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/StreamSocketService.html) states:

> If the operation completes successfully, the [handler] is invoked with the number of bytes transferred. Otherwise it is invoked with `0`.

On the other hand, *composed operations*, such as [`boost::asio::async_read()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) may be invoked with a non-success `error_code` and a non-zero `bytes_transferred`.  For example, if an `async_read()` operation is initiated and set to read 1024 bytes before completing, it may invoke `async_read_some()` multiple times.  If 256 bytes are received and then the connection is closed, the `async_read()` handler will have a non-zero `error_code` and `bytes_transferred` will indicate that 256 bytes of the buffer are valid.

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5083bb4b1e77b1b) a connection persisting even when certain operations fail:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void noop() {}

void print_status(
  const boost::system::error_code& error,
  std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  std::cout << "error = (" << error << ") " << error.message() << "; "
               "bytes_transferred = " << bytes_transferred
            << std::endl;
}

void run_io_service(std::string message, boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
{
  std::cout << message << ": ";
  io_service.run();
  io_service.reset();
}

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

  // Create all I/O objects.
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 0));
  tcp::socket socket1(io_service);
  tcp::socket socket2(io_service);

  // Connect the sockets.
  acceptor.async_accept(socket1, boost::bind(&noop));
  socket2.async_connect(acceptor.local_endpoint(), boost::bind(&noop));
  io_service.run();
  io_service.reset();

  const char data[] = "hello\n";
  char buffer[128];

  // Create an async receive operation and cancel it.
  socket1.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), &print_status);
  socket1.cancel();
  run_io_service("async_receive1", io_service);

  // Create an async write operation.
  socket1.async_send(boost::asio::buffer(data), &print_status);
  run_io_service("async_send1", io_service);

  // Shutdown the receive side of the socket then create an async
  // receive operation.
  socket1.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_receive);
  socket1.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), &print_status);
  run_io_service("async_receive2", io_service);

  // Create an async write operation.
  socket1.async_send(boost::asio::buffer(data), &print_status);
  run_io_service("async_send2", io_service);
}
```

Output:

```
async_receive1: error = (system:125) Operation canceled; bytes_transferred = 0
async_send1: error = (system:0) Success; bytes_transferred = 7
async_receive2: error = (asio.misc:2) End of file; bytes_transferred = 0
async_send2: error = (system:0) Success; bytes_transferred = 7
```

Comment: Nice answer! It seems though that you say no and no, but then detail a case of no and yes (the partial transmission case).

Comment: @Dronz Thanks.  I intended for the short answer to be specific to the _non-composed_ operations asked in the question, where if an error occurs, `bytes_transferred` will be `0`.  For non-composed operations, this is not always true.  The answer is updated to stress the differences and provide some more insight into the documentation.